# What is the use of “true” when writing a function, which given a key and map, returns “true”

Tags: clojure

Write a function which, given a key and map, returns `true` if the map contains an entry with that key and its value is `nil`.

Solution I came across:

```
#(nil? (get %2 % true))
```

Can someone please explain the use of `true` in

```
(get %2 % true) ?
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's a default value that will be returned in the case of absence of the key

```
;; key exists
(get {:a 1} :a 2)
#=> 1
;; key doesn't exist (default value is returned)
(get {:a 1} :b 2)
#=> 2
;; key exists and it's value is nil
(get {:a nil} :a 2)
#=> nil
;; key doesn't exist, nil is returned
(get {:a 1} :b)
#=> nil
```

some docs could be found here

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get

so the idea is that `(get {:a 1} :b)` will always return `nil` because key doesn't exist. In this case `(nil? (get {:a 1} :b))` will return true, which is not what we want. That's why adding this default value is necessary. So `nil` will be returned only in the case when the actual value is `nil`.

The value true is not special here. 85 would work just as well: any value other than nil fixes the problem.

Comment: Great! Thanks a ton!!